# PHP, mark checkboxes as checked from database array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have scoured the net trying to find my exact solution and cannot find anything relevant to my situation.  I need to save 2 different checkboxes as a single array to Wordpress as custom post meta.  I can make this part work, what I am having trouble with is marking the checkboxes as checked if they exist in the array. I have not included the surrounding meta box code, just the portions relevant to my issue.

Here how I am trying to display the checked boxes (this is not working):

```
<?php $AMP = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bta_propertyAMP'); ?>
<input type="checkbox" class="regular-text" name="bta_propertyAMP[]" value="30" <?php echo (in_array('30', $AMP)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> 30 AMP
<input type="checkbox" class="regular-text" name="bta_propertyAMP[]" value="50" <?php echo (in_array('50', $AMP)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> 50 AMP
```

Here is how I am saving this (this part is working):

```
<?php 
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bta_propertyAMP', true);
$new = array();
$amps = $_POST['bta_propertyAMP'];
$count = count( $amps );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
 if ( $amps[$i] != '' ) :
   $new[$i]['bta_propertyAMP'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $amps[$i] ) );
 endif;
}

if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bta_propertyAMP', $new );
} elseif ( empty($new) && $old ) {
  delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'bta_propertyAMP', $old );
}
?>
```

Comment: It might be possible that $AMP has multiple arrays within it, so something like $AMP[0][], which might be resulting your in_array to be always false. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got this working, there is probably a better way but this does work if anyone else runs into this. I looped through the array and created a variable for each checkbox that I could then check outside the loop if it was true.

```
<?php 
$amps = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bta_propertyAMP', true);
  foreach($amps as $amp) :
    if($amp['bta_propertyAMP'] == 30) { $amp30 = '1'; }
    if($amp['bta_propertyAMP'] == 50) { $amp50 = '1'; }
endforeach; 
?>
<input type="checkbox" class="regular-text" name="bta_propertyAMP[]" value="30" <?php echo ($amp30 == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> 30 AMP
<input type="checkbox" class="regular-text" name="bta_propertyAMP[]" value="50" <?php echo ($amp50 == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> 50 AMP
```

Comment: Can you give us the ouput of `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bta_propertyAMP', true));`?

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["bta_propertyAMP"]=> string(2) "30" } [1]=> array(1) { ["bta_propertyAMP"]=> string(2) "50" } }`

Comment: As I thought - I've added to my answer, you just need to add the array pointers

Answer (score 0):

The conditional in your second AMP checkbox is also checking for

```
in_array('30', $AMP)
```

When you probably meant to have it check for 50:

```
in_array('50', $AMP)
```

It looks like you actually just need to replace them with

```
in_array('30', $AMP[0])
```

and

```
in_array('50', $AMP[1])
```

Sorry I'm now on mobile - you may need to remove the single quotes around the 30 and the 50, but the array pointers in the square brackets are what you need, since your meta value is an array of arrays (hence why the loop worked)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it, but still, no dice.  The array is being saved correctly to the database, but I cannot get the checkboxes to show checked